# normal form theory

Tags: dynamical-systems

My question consider the reason for calculating normal form.

given vector field: $$\dot{x}=F(x),\  \ x\in \mathbb{R^n}$$ we try to bring the system to normal form by a sequence of transformation but what is the reason for it ? what information the normal form give to us?

If one has a reference with examples for the information we get from normal form I will be glad.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the reason for this to be able to say something meaningful about the original system. As an example, consider an equation
$$
\dot x=f(x,\alpha)
$$
that depends on a scalar parameter $\alpha$. Assume that the equilibrium $\hat x$ is non-hyperbolic at $\alpha=0$ (i.e., $f'(\hat x,0)=0$). Then under quite general assumption on $f$ it is possible to prove that there exists an invertible change of variable and parameter such that in new coordinate we have the following normal form:
$$
\dot y=\mu\pm y^2.
$$
This last equation is very simple to analyze (it exhibits what is called fold bifurcation) and hence the original system also experiences the same bifurcation.

A more extensive treatment along with additional references can be found at http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Normal_forms

Comment: I was thinking about showing this - "Then under quite general assumption on $f$ it is possible to prove that there exists an invertible change of variable and parameter", any proof or reference??

Comment: @BAYMAX Almost any book that has the words "bifurcations" in its contents. E.g., Wiggins Introduction to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos.